# Markov chain $Z_{n+1}=\max(X_n+Z_n,0)$

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Let $(X_n)_{n\ge O}$ independent i.i.d random variables such that $P(X_0=1)=p$ and $P(X_0=−1)=1−p.$
Let $a\in\Bbb{N}$

> I would like to prove that $$Z_0=a\;\;\mbox{and}\;\;\forall n\ge 1\;\;Z_{n+1}=\max(X_n+Z_n,0)$$ is a markov chain with space $E$ to determine and to find an "interpretation". And to prove that $Z_n$ is irreducible.

Ok so we have $Z_{n+1}=f(Z_n,X_n)$ with $f(x,y)=\max(x+y,0)$ so that $Z_n$ is a markov chain.

Now not sure about $E.$ We have $Z_1=\max(X_1+a,0)\in\{0,-1+a,a+1\}.$

> which means that $E=\Bbb{N}$ am I correct ? How can I interpret $Z_n?$
>
> For the fact that is irreducible, I just need to prove that $P(i,i+1)>0$ and $P(i+1,i)>0$ right ? How can I do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$E = \Bbb N_0$ and $Z_n$ is a random walk, that stays at $0$ rather than going to negative.

You could interprete it as a game, where a player tosses a coin and wins with probability $p$. Everytime he is winning he gets 1 credit, when he is losing he loses 1 credit as long as he has nonnegative credit value.

Irreducibility follows from the definition. For a $n > j$ there is always a positive chance to go in $n-j$ steps from $j$ to state $n$.

Comment: thanks, do you have an idea to prove that is irreducible ?